# How to add an extra file (needed for the app) into Inno setup vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inno-setup

I have an extra file that is called by my VB.NET code and its path is `"Application.StartupPath & "\List.txt"`

I need this file in the installation directory of my app, near the main executable.

What can i do?

Comment: Please include your `.isl` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line under [Files] section, mentioning the desired file's Source and I puth `DestDir:` same as the executable's `DestDir:`.

Like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\.NET Projects\SampleProject\Sample\bin\Release\myApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\.NET Projects\SampleProject\Sample\bin\Release\List.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Doing this will install those two files in the same directory. Then I can access the `List.txt` file using this path: `"Application.StartupPath & "\List.txt"`